# Access a file created by a separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, io, file-copying

I have a problem aith multithreading when copying and accessing files.

I have a service, that downloads and unpacks a Zip archive, then it copies a file from unzipped folder to the right location:

```
//Download, and uzip archive...

//Copy a needed file to its right location
File.Copy(fileName, fileDestination);
```

Then I start a separate thread, that needs to access the copied files:

```
TheadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s => processCopiedFile(fileDestination));
```

Here's the code fragment from ProcessCopiedFile:

```
private void ProcessCopiedFile(string filePath)
{
    ...
    //Load the file, previously copied here
    var xml = XDocument.Load(filePath);
    ...
    //Do other work...
}
```

The XDoument.Load call fails with exception:

```
The process cannot access the file <FileName> because it is used by another process.
```

Seems like File.Copy keeps the result file locked. When do all work synchronuously, it works without errors.
Have you any thoughts?
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

File.Copy does not keep anything open or locked, it is an atomic operation which requires some time, depending of course on Disk/Network I/O and file size.

Of course while moving from sync to async you should make sure you do not access the destination file while the copy is still in progress.

Comment: First I call File.Copy (synchronuously), Then I start new Thread. Cause File.Copy is called synchronuously, it guaranteed finishes its work before new Thread starts. Or I am mistaken somewhere?

Comment: +1 - Just to clarify the last part: Windows keeps an exclusive lock on the file, while it's being copied.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file with a stream to avoid windows lock from File.Copy

```
using(var s = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath))
{
    using(var fs = new FileStream(newLocation, FileMode.Create))
    {
        s.WriteTo(fs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Copying files properly is rocket science.  Need to take care of preserving file attributes and alternate streams in the file.  Don't do it yourself.